# Membership provider GetUser(username,false) returning null for some of the users

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership

My user exists both in aspnet_membership and aspnet_users, but its not working with GetUser method.

```
MembershipUser user = membershipProvider.GetUser(model.UserName, false);
```

Note: This works with some of the users but not for few.

Not getting whats going wrong, unable to figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.